# Is it possible to connect MS PowerBI with remote R?

Tags: r, powerbi

I have a remote and powerful R server. Is there any chance to use it from within PowerBI? Or do I have to route the communication via a local R installation?

I want to work in PowerBI Desktop to utilize for its interface and to generate graphs and utilize my already-existing R infrastructure. I can write a wrapper script to let my local R access the remote R, but it would be more elegant if the connection handling would be done natively in PowerBI (using some dedicated R package written for this purpose or just `RServe`/`svSocket`/?) .

Comment: @PaulHiemstra just saw that it's possible with Power BI Desktop. [Create Power BI Visuals using R](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-r-visuals/). I had the hosted service in mind

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Nice, comments seem to vanish rather quickly here :).

Comment: @PaulHiemstra if you have to handle a lot of data, it *does* become a problem even with Desktop. It's certainly impossible to work *this* way with the Power BI service. This will also be a concern with the upcoming on-premise version that will run on SSRS.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The page you linked refers to the local installation of R. I am asking about the remote.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski Can you access the remote R server from within an R script locally? In that case you can simply create a local wrapper script to send commands to the remote server.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra the OP is asking a very different question. The question is about the cloud-hosted Power BI *Service* . The remote server would have to be an Azure VM or an Analytics service. Analytics does include R and does *target* Power BI.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski why do you want to use R? For visualizations or analysis? For analysis, wouldn't it be better to process the data first, then post the results to Power BI? That's offered out-of-the-box with Azure Machine Learning.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is not clear to me, it feels like PowerBI is running locally and the R server remotely. OP could you make the question more clear. Is PowerBI running locally or in the cloud?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra there is no other "remote" offering right now, unless you count the on-prem version that's included in the SQL Server vNext CTP (the one with Linux support).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I actually want to work in PowerBI Desktop and utilize my already-existing R infrastructure. And yes, I can write a wrapper script to let my local R access the remote R, but it would be more elegant if the connection handling (with accompanying R package) would be done natively in PowerBI

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski didn't you say in a comment that you don't want the local server? Anyway, you need a *local* R installation in order to talk to R *Server*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK. So I simply use local R as a proxy, and PowerBI Desktop wouldn't even now that the actual data/R scripts are originating from the remote server?

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski hope you found an answer because I'm going to delete mine. Seems some people like downvoting without actually offering (or knowing of) a solution

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand. Just wait a moment. I have flagged your answer for moderator to explain why the downvotes (maybe they can guess?)

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski in the meantime, the Power BI blog published three more articles on R scripting. The most relevant to you is [Running R Scripts in Power BI Desktop](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-r-scripts/) `You can run R scripts directly in Power BI Desktop, and import the resulting datasets into a Power BI Desktop data model.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R visuals *are* supported in the Power BI Service since [July 2016](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/r-visuals-in-powerbi-service/). The feature has to be [activated by the administrator](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13455279-r-visuals-in-power-bi-service) of the Power BI portal. According to the blog post, you have to create the dashboard [with the Power BI Desktop version](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-r-visuals/) and publish it to the portal.

Power BI adds new features every month which makes it very easy to fall behind!

**UPDATE**

Three more blog posts on R scripting were added recently:

- [Running R Scripts in Power BI Desktop](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-r-scripts/)
- [Create Power BI visuals using R](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-r-visuals/)
- and [Use an external R IDE with Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-r-ide/)

The most relevant to the question seems to be [Running R Scripts in Power BI Desktop](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-r-scripts/), which shows how R Scripts can be used as *data sources* in Power BI.

Go to the *Get Data* menuy and select *R Script* from the *All* category.

For example, to load the `mtcars` dataset, go to *Get Data > All > R Script>* and enter `data(mtdata)` as the script. Power BI will display a list of frames to load or edit.

It's possible to edit the frame's data using Power BI's query editor just like other sources, before loading the data into a Power BI dataset.

After that, the dataset is available for use, just like any other Power BI dataset

You should check the [Power BI R Script Gallery](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/R-Script-Showcase/bd-p/RVisuals). Most of the scripts there are visuals, but at least [this one](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/R-Script-Showcase/Map-with-connecting-lines/m-p/80294) uses R to generate the source data

Comment: It wasn't me. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Are *R visuals* limited only for graphics? I actually want to use R for input data generation.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski R scripts can be used as data sources too. I added links to relevant articles and the R script gallery